# How can I add a custom title, image and caption to my facebook share button?

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to add a custom title, caption, etc to the facebook share button so that when the page is shared, it appears with the custom title, image. Any idea how I can do this, I tried the sdk but it didn't work, the meta tags don't seem to work as well, any help appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add Open Graph Tags to your source. There are a few required ones that you should always implement, you can find all the information you need in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/

Facebook reads those tags automatically when you share something. If it does not work immediately, refresh/debug the URL here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Here is an additional link about OG Tags: http://ogp.me/

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your Script:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: 'og.likes',
    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
        object: {
            "og": {
                "url": your_url,
                "title": your_title,
                "image": {
                    "url": your_image_URL
                }
            }
        }
    })
}, function(response){});
```